# Script to check for email subject not in inbox runs without error but not as expected. Not sure what is wrong with syntax.

Tags: google-apps-script

I get an automated email when an event occurs, but need to be notified if it isn't received. It's easy to overlook something that doesn't happen.

Here's what I have, but the var c remains 0 when script ends (I'm expecting it to not be 0 if email is found, and be 0 and send email if subject is not found.

```
function CheckForSubjectInEmail() {

var threads = GmailApp.search("in:Inbox");  
var subject = "Testing";
var c = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

  for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
    var msg = messages[m].getSubject();

    // Does the message subject match?
    if (msg = subject) {
    c = c++
    }

 if (c = 0) {  
  MailApp.sendEmail("email@domain.com",
                   "Important email not received.",
                   "The Testing email has not yet been received.");    
    }   
   }
  }  
 }
```

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few problems - two of them work together to explain your observation.

First, you've used assignment (`=`) where you meant to test for equality (`==` or `===`). The way your comparisons are written, you're *assigning* `subject` to `msg`, and `0` to `c`, and then testing their ["truthiness"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). (Turns out `msg` is always "truthy" unless it's `null` or empty, while 'c' is always "falsy", because it's always `0`.) You should instead have:

```
if (msg == subject) {
  ...
```

and

```
if (c == 0) {
  ...
```

If you're wondering about which equality operator to use, see the ridiculously popular question [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

You should be able to see the second problem clearer if you format your code properly. I personally like [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org) for this. Here's how the code cleans up:

```js
function CheckForSubjectInEmail() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:Inbox");
  var subject = "Testing";
  var c = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var msg = messages[m].getSubject();

      // Does the message subject match?
      if (msg == subject) {
        c = c++
      }

      if (c == 0) {
        MailApp.sendEmail("email@domain.com",
          "Important email not received.",
          "The Testing email has not yet been received.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you see it? The `if (c == 0)` comparison isn't at the "end" of the function, rather it's inside the loop, so if ANY message doesn't have a matching subject it will fire off an error message. (That's not a normal situation, but since subjects can be edited on emails within a thread, it's possible.) You should move that outside of the loop.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now that I see it :)

Answer (score 0):

A boolean check uses the == syntax. it should read

```
if(c == 0){..}
```

and

```
if(msg == subject)
```

also I saw c = c++; You could simple express it c++;